# WCF 4.0 with PHP 5 Client

Tags: php, wcf, webservice-client

I'm trying to make an PHP Client for an WCF Webservice. But i get some Errors when i call the functions of the service.

App.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior"
           name="GSC.Wcf.Services.CartService">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              contract="GSC.Wcf.Services.ICartService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/CartService" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Function:

```
> public int Addiere(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
```

PHP-Request:

```
> $client = new SoapClient("http://localhost:8731/CartService?wsdl");
>
> $result = $client->Addiere(2,4);
```

for these function i get an Error like that:

> "Uncaught SoapFault exception: [a:DeserializationFailed] the
>   Formatierer formatter has realeased an exception during the
>   deserilization of the message: Failed to deserialize the request body
>   of the message is intended for operation "Addiere". The end-element
>   "Body" aus Namespace "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" was
>   expected. Found was the element "param1" of Namespace"".

In German:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [a:DeserializationFailed]
>   Der Formatierer hat beim Deserialisieren der Nachricht eine Ausnahme
>   ausgelÃ¶st: Fehler beim Deserialisieren des TextkÃ¶rpers der
>   Anforderungsnachricht fÃ¼r Vorgang "Addiere". Es wurde das Endelement
>   "Body" aus Namespace "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
>   erwartet. Gefunden wurde "Element "param1" aus Namespace """. Zeile 2,
>   Position 148. in C:\xampp\htdocs\TestClient\Client.php:6 Stack trace:
>   0 C:\xampp\htdocs\TestClient\Client.php(6): SoapClient->__call('Addiere', Array) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\TestClient\Client.php(6): SoapClient->Addiere(2, 4) #2
>   {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\TestClient\Client.php on line 6

But this function is working:

C#

```
> public string Message()
        {
            return "WORD";
        }
```

PHP

```
> $result = $client->Message();
var_dump($result);
```

result

> object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["MessageResult"]=> string(4) "WORD" } WORD

the only problem is that the return type is no string.

Can anybody guess whats wrong, or shell i post some more stuff like wsdl ?
Or does anybody knows good sources where i can look up how i can get the right konfigurations to communicate with my service ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Problem solved.

When calling a method with more than 2 Parameters you need to put them in an array like this

`$result = $client->Addiere(array("a" => 2, "b" => 3))->AddiereResult;`

and the otherProblem was the return typ, this is solved with

```
....->AddiereResult;
```

not sure what the last part means but it works i will figure this out.

Comment: Congrats on the solution.  When you are able, please mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others might learn from your success.  Cheers~